# Nested enumeration

Tags: lists, enumerate, nesting

I'm trying to create a list of the following type:

> 1a) Apples
>
> 1b) Bananas
>
> 1c) Oranges
>
> 2a) Tomatoes
>
> 2b) Carrots
>
> 3) Bread
>
> 4a) Cake
>
> 4b) Cookies

I tried to use both `enumitem` and `easylist` and read some answers of related questions, but I wasn't successful.

Comment: Could you please show what you tried so far? Will there also be a "parent"   to 1a), 1b) and 1c)?

Comment: If had "parents" then it would be easy to do it with easylist. The point is that I don't

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The proposed syntax is

- a simple `\item` steps the main counter and just uses it;
- `\item[+]` steps the main counter and prints it followed by the secondary one;
- `\item[=]` only steps the secondary counter.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcounter{bienumi}
\newcounter{bienumii}[bienumi]
\renewcommand{\thebienumi}{%
  \arabic{bienumi}\ifnest\alph{bienumii}\fi
}
\newif\ifnest

\newenvironment{bienum}{\enumerate\let\item\biitem}{\endenumerate}

\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\biitem}{o}
 {
  \nesttrue
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {
    \nestfalse
    \stepcounter{bienumi}
   }
   {
    \str_case:nn {#1}
     {
      {+}{\stepcounter{bienumi}\stepcounter{bienumii}}
      {=}{\stepcounter{bienumii}}
     }
   }
  \@item[\thebienumi)]
 }
\makeatother\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{bienum}
\item[+] Apples

\item[=] Bananas

\item[=] Oranges

\item[+] Tomatoes

\item[=] Carrots

\item Bread

\item[+] Cake

\item[=] Cookies
\end{bienum}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You made the things so easy....Greetings....

Comment: I confess that it's a complete black box for me, but it works beautifully!    Thanks so much!

Comment: BTW I hope you're safe there in Italy!

Comment: @Gil Staying at home as much as possible. Thanks for caring!

Comment: @egreg - The code works perfectly! Thank you! I'd like to reduce the line spacing between the enumerate items, but the code fails if I try to add [noitemsep] to the \newenvironment{bienum} line. Is there a way to include [noitemsep] to reduce line spacing? Thank you again for this code!!

Comment: @RosesBouquet You can change `\enumerate` into `\enumerate[noitemsep]`, but you also need `\usepackage{enumitem}`.

Comment: @egreg - Perfect! Thank you!!